# Backup of a Linux desktop on a Synology NAS (DS 5.2) using backintime

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, nas, synology

I am trying to setup a backup of my Linux desktop machine on a Synology NAS with backintime.

However, I am stuck with the following error message:

```
Entfernter Rechner <nas.ip.address> unterstützt 'rsync -rtDH --links --no-p --no-g --no-o  --dry-run --chmod=Du+wx /tmp/tmpAOVRI9 --rsh="ssh -p 22 " "<user>@<nas.ip.address>:/volume2/backup"' nicht:
3072
```

Translation:

```
Remote server <nas.ip.address> does not support 'rsync -rtDH --links --no-p --no-g --no-o  --dry-run --chmod=Du+wx /tmp/tmpAOVRI9 --rsh="ssh -p 22 " "<user>@<nas.ip.address>:/volume2/backup"':
3072
```

Setup:

- Synology NAS: DS214play, running DS 5.2-5644
- Desktop: Linux Mint 17.2
- backintime: v1.0.34

What I have done so far:

- I have setup the NAS, so I can login as `<user>` using the users public ssh key. (Thus, `ssh -p 22 <user>@<nas.ip.address>` works fine.)
- I got sshfs working, so `sshfs -p 22 -o ServerAliveInterval=240 -o idmap=user <user>@<nas.ip.address>:/ </mountpoint/` works fine. (However, `sshfs -p 22 -o ServerAliveInterval=240 -o idmap=user <user>@<nas.ip.address>:/volume2/backup </mountpoint/` fails with `<user>@<nas.ip.address>:/volume2/backup: No such file or directory`, even though the directory exists on the nas.

When I run the command above in a shell on the desktop, I get the following error message (I've also tried without `volum2/backup` but the result is the same):

```
rsync -rtDH --links --no-p --no-g --no-o  --dry-run --chmod=Du+wx /tmp/tmpAOVRI9 --rsh="ssh -p 22 " "<user>@<nas.ip.address>:/volume2/backup"
Permission denied, please try again.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

There was a [very good wiki](http://wiki.qedinux.be/index.php?title=BackInTime_to_Synology_DSM_5) about setting up a Synology NAS for BackInTime that I always linked. But that is gone (at least it doesn't show up anymore, history is still available). So I will add it here

---

## Issue

BackInTime cannot use Synology DSM 5 because the SSH connection to the NAS refers to a different root file system than SFTP does. With SSH you access the real root, with SFTP you access a fake root (/volume1)

## Solution

Mount `/volume1/backups` to `/volume1/volume1/backups`

## HowTo

- Make a new volume named `volume1` (if it doesn't exist yet)
- Enable User Home Service (Control Panel / User)
- Make a new share named `backups` on `volume1`
- Make a new share named `volume1` on `volume1` (It must be the same name)
- Make a new user named `backup`
- Give to user `backup` rights Read/Write to share `backups` and `volume1`, permission for FTP
- Enable SSH (Control Panel / Terminal & SNMP / Terminal)
- Enable SFTP (Control Panel / File Service / FTP / SFTP)
- Since DSM 5.1: Enable Backup Service (Backup & Replication / Backup Service)
- Log on as root by SSH
- Modify the shell of user `backup`. Set it to `/bin/sh`
- Make a new directory `/volume1/volume1/backups`

  ```
  mkdir /volume1/volume1/backups
  ```
- Mount `/volume1/backups` on `/volume1/volume1/backups`

  ```
  mount -o bind /volume1/backups /volume1/volume1/backups
  ```
- To auto-mount it make a script `/usr/syno/etc/rc.d/S99zzMountBind.sh`

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  start()
  {
         /bin/mount -o bind /volume1/backups /volume1/volume1/backups
  }

  stop()
  {
         /bin/umount /volume1/volume1/backups
  }

  case "$1" in
         start) start ;;
         stop) stop ;;
         *) ;;
  esac
  ```
- On the workstation on which you try to use BIT make SSH keys for user `backup`, send the public key to the NAS

  ```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/backup_id_rsa
  ssh-add ~/.ssh/backup_id_rsa
  ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/backup_id_rsa.pub backup@<synology-ip>
  ssh backup@<synology-ip>
  ```
- Now you can use BackInTime to perform your backup to your NAS with the user `backup`.

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm member of BIT Dev-Team</sub>

Comment: It is also very important to check that home folder permissions on Synology are 755 (drwxr-xr-x). Otherwise ssh with key won't work and ask password instead. By default home folder was created with 777 permissions in my case (DSM 6.1).

Comment: [this information has been integrated in backitime FAQ with up date for DSM 6](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime/wiki/Hardware-Specific-Setups)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution of Germar, I had to add a custom rsync flag in the profile settings:

- Go to  "Export options"
- Check "Paste additional options to rsync"
- Add --rsync-path=/*path-to-rsync*/rsync in the text field beside

On my Synology station rsync is located at /bin/rsync.